# WPF Combobox always displays icon of the first element

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a combobox in a custom window where I display a language short name its corresponding icon

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="LanguagesListBoxSelectionChanged" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
                                  Visibility="{TemplateBinding IsLanguageSwitchComboBoxVisible}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=Languages}"
                                  IsEnabled="True" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="90" Height="28"
                                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path= SelectedLanguage}">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding LanguageName}" Margin="0 0 4 0"></TextBlock>
                                        <Image Height="24" Width="24">
                                            <Image.Source>
                                                <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding LanguagePicture, Converter={StaticResource DebugDummyConverter}}" />
                                            </Image.Source>
                                        </Image>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
```

Custom window:

```
public class CustomTitleBarWindow : Window
    {
        public CustomTitleBarWindow()
        {
            Languages = new List<LanguageModel>()
            {
                new() {Id="ru", LanguageName = "RU", LanguagePicture = "../../Images/ru.ico" },
                new() {Id="en", LanguageName = "EN", LanguagePicture = "../../Images/en.ico" }
            };
            SelectedLanguage = Languages.First();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedLanguageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedLanguage", typeof(LanguageModel), typeof(CustomTitleBarWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public LanguageModel SelectedLanguage
        {
            get => (LanguageModel)GetValue(SelectedLanguageProperty);
            set => SetValue(SelectedLanguageProperty, value);
        }
...
```

Item list displays correctly.

The issue is when I select any item, the combobox displays a proper text ("*EN*" or "*RU*") but the icon displayed is the one at "*../../Images/ru.ico*" path.

If I put "*../../Images/en.ico*" into the list first then the "english" icon will be displayed no matter what item was selected.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding LanguageName}" Margin="0 0 4 0"></TextBlock>
                <Image Height="24" Width="24" Source="{Binding LanguagePicture, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And an ImageConverter

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

The problem is that BitmapImage needs a value immediately whereas binding provides it later.